# PHP Based Project Management Application (Scrum/Agile)

Tags: php, project-management, agile, scrum

I've been fiddling with Redmine in the past few days and not 100% happy with the way it organises tasks etc.

I need a open source PHP based solution that is like Redmine or even VersionOne to assist our small team of 3 developers with project management.

We basically use Scrum, and would love to be able to create projects, break them down into user stories, and then further break stories down into tasks.

We typically use also size tasks and user stories using the PERT analysis formula.

Comment: There are already a lot of similar questions, e.g: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/426458/recommendations-for-project-management-software-for-scrum

Comment: That link doesn't offer specifically PHP based solutions.

Comment: @M4N that linked question has been removed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For open source Scrum tools information (list of tools, reviews), you should look at http://www.opensourcescrum.com/

Comment: I never liked giving a link as an answer, but this link is (now) not very useful either. Contains dead links, links to paid solutions and provides no information about whether a solution is php based.

Comment: There are no links to php based open source scrum tools as asked by op. Did the OP find any tools which can be shared here for others looking for same solution. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You could try [The Bug Genie](http://thebuggenie.com/features#agile). It's not been specifically designed for Scrum, but does support Agile development.

Comment: not getting installed on godaddy hosting , file permission issues

Comment: Free version doesn't include kanban/scrum boards.

Comment: @nessa.gp - Version 3 supports agile development, without a board. Version 4, which is currently in beta supports all kind of white boards: http://thebuggenie.org/features/next

Answer (score 1):

the-scrum was a PHP based solution

Comment: This project is pretty much dead -> Released:December, 27th 2010